# Kanji to romaji converter in pure Java?

Tags: java, translation

I want to convert Japanese kanjis to romaji (or kana) in Android.

The most popular library for this is [Kakasi](http://kakasi.namazu.org/), it is not always right (can't be) but still very good.
PROBLEM: It is not in Java. I need a Java library.

Do you know any maintained Java open source library that does that?

A guy called Kenichi has posted a [kakasi-java-0.4.0-src.tar.gz on his blog](http://blog.kenichimaehashi.com/?article=13048363750) saying he saved the file but the original project does not exist anymore. Anyone knows more about this? Is the project still living somewhere else, or is this file my best starting point?

Comment: This is not very Java-related and mostly data-related. Dictionary data like this are usually not very open, but kanji pronunciation must be open enough. Kakasi was last updated in 2004, which is _eight years_ ago. It seems dead. Its dictionary data is still relevant; you could port Kakasi's algorithms to Java and reuse these data.

Comment: Data is not a problem (Kakasi's data is open and fine). It IS Java-related. You are right that I could port Kakasi to Java, but if someone has done it already I would rather not duplicate their work.

Comment: This question now lives at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28441/java-library-to-transform-kanji-katakana-hiragana-to-romaji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.atilika.org it's by far the most complete solution I've found.

Comment: Great! It is indeed the only modern solution available in pure Java.

Answer (score 4):

The project is dead but now it's living somewhere else:
https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/kakasi-java

Comment: Accepting due to lack of other open-source-based answers. This project is my fork from kakasi-java-0.4.0-src.tar.gz, so if anyone knows a newer version of the main project please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I searched Kakasi/Java but I could not find. The site must have been completely closed.

But for another way, this web service might help you:

http://www.kawa.net/works/ajax/romanize/japanese-e.html

それでは頑張ってください！

Answer (score 0):

I have found another one: [Mecab](http://code.google.com/p/mecab/)

It seems to have a Java version: http://code.google.com/p/mecab/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fmecab%2Fjava

UPDATE: Unfortunately Mecab-java is just a JNI binding, not 100% pure Java, which makes it more difficult to use on Android for instance.