# How to convert Hiragana, Katakana or Kanji to Romaji using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to categorize Japanese words base on there first character. For example:

Group 1 
All Japanese word that starts from

```
あa いi うu えe おo
かka きki くku けke こko
```

Group 2
All Japanese word that starts from

```
さsa しshi すsu せse そso
たta ちchi つtsu てte とto
```

What makes it difficult is some characters in Japanese are written to different type such as Hiragana, Katakana and Kanji which words are written differently but same in meaning.

It might be possible if I could only convert hiragana, katakana or kanji to romaji.

Can someone help me, Is it possible in PHP? or is their a plugin in Wordpress that can do this?

Comment: If the word begins with hiragana or katakana, it's easy to group them. However, with kanji, you're going to have issues because take for example, 腹痛, the readings are ふくつう and はらいた. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5827439) for more information on this.

Comment: I see, thanks for your insight Dave, yes that's really my problem. Although I find KAKASI interesting but how could I use it? Is it really applicable to my situation? Just additional Info. We are using a shared server, that's why I don't have a full control to the server.

Comment: KAKASHI is a bundled UNIX application, and since you mentioned "shared", I guess that's not an option. I recommend taking a look at [Yahoo's API](http://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/jlp/furigana/v1/furigana.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function with repeated lines of simple string replacements.

```php
function HiraganaToRomaji($hold) {

    $hold = str_replace("つ", "tsu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("きゃ", "kya", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("きゅ", "kyu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("きょ", "kyo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("しゃ", "sha", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("しゅ", "shu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("しょ", "sho", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("し", "shi", $hold);

    $hold = str_replace("ちゃ", "cha", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ちゅ", "chu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ちょ", "cho", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ち", "chi", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ひゃ", "hya", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ひゅ", "hyu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ひょ", "hyo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("りゃ", "rya", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("りゅ", "ryu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("りょ", "ryo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぎゃ", "gya", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぎゅ", "gyu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぎょ", "gyo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("びゃ", "bya", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("びゅ", "byu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("びょ", "byo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぴゃ", "pya", $hold);

    $hold = str_replace("ぴゅ", "pyu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぴょ", "pyo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("じゃ", "ja", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("じゅ", "ju", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("じょ", "jo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ば", "ba", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("だ", "da", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("が", "ga", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("は", "ha", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("か", "ka", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ま", "ma", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぱ", "pa", $hold);

    $hold = str_replace("ら", "ra", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("さ", "sa", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("た", "ta", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("わ", "wa", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("や", "ya", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ざ", "za", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("な", "na", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("あ", "a", $hold);

    $hold = str_replace("べ", "be", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("で", "de", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("げ", "ge", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("へ", "he", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("け", "ke", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("め", "me", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぺ", "pe", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("れ", "re", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("せ", "se", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("て", "te", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぜ", "ze", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ね", "ne", $hold);

    $hold = str_replace("え", "e", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("び", "bi", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぎ", "gi", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ひ", "hi", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("き", "ki", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("み", "mi", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぴ", "pi", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("り", "ri", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("じ", "ji", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("に", "ni", $hold);

    $hold = str_replace("い", "i", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぼ", "bo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ど", "do", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ご", "go", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ほ", "ho", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("こ", "ko", $hold);

    $hold = str_replace("も", "mo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぽ", "po", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ろ", "ro", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("そ", "so", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("と", "to", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("を", "wo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("よ", "yo", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぞ", "zo", $hold);

    $hold = str_replace("の", "no", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("お", "o", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぶ", "bu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぐ", "gu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ふ", "fu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("く", "ku", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("む", "mu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぷ", "pu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("る", "ru", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("す", "su", $hold);

    $hold = str_replace("ゆ", "yu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ず", "zu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ぬ", "nu", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("う", "u", $hold);
    $hold = str_replace("ん", "n", $hold);

    $hold = preg_replace("/っ([a-z])/", "$1$1", $hold);

    return $hold;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the replacement of し come after しゅ?

Comment: @Oli true! ty - edited

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hiragana javascript version. You could port it over by using PHP's `preg_replace`

You could also make a katakana version this way.
However, Kanji would be a lot more complicated.

```
function romajiToHiragana(hold) {
    hold = hold.replace(/tsu/g, "つ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/kya/g, "きゃ");
    hold = hold.replace(/kyu/g, "きゅ");
    hold = hold.replace(/kyo/g, "きょ");
    hold = hold.replace(/sha/g, "しゃ");
    hold = hold.replace(/shi/g, "し"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/shu/g, "しゅ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/sho/g, "しょ");
    hold = hold.replace(/chi/g, "ち"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/cha/g, "ちゃ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/chu/g, "ちゅ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/cho/g, "ちょ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/hya/g, "ひゃ");
    hold = hold.replace(/hyu/g, "ひゅ");
    hold = hold.replace(/hyo/g, "ひょ");
    hold = hold.replace(/rya/g, "りゃ");
    hold = hold.replace(/ryu/g, "りゅ");
    hold = hold.replace(/ryo/g, "りょ");
    hold = hold.replace(/gya/g, "ぎゃ");
    hold = hold.replace(/gyu/g, "ぎゅ");
    hold = hold.replace(/gyo/g, "ぎょ");
    hold = hold.replace(/bya/g, "びゃ");
    hold = hold.replace(/byu/g, "びゅ");
    hold = hold.replace(/byo/g, "びょ");
    hold = hold.replace(/pya/g, "ぴゃ");
    hold = hold.replace(/pyu/g, "ぴゅ");
    hold = hold.replace(/pyo/g, "ぴょ");
    hold = hold.replace(/ja/g, "じゃ");
    hold = hold.replace(/ju/g, "じゅ");
    hold = hold.replace(/jo/g, "じょ");
    hold = hold.replace(/ba/g, "ば"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/da/g, "だ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ga/g, "が"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ha/g, "は"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ka/g, "か"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ma/g, "ま"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/pa/g, "ぱ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ra/g, "ら"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/sa/g, "さ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ta/g, "た"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/wa/g, "わ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ya/g, "や"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/za/g, "ざ");
    hold = hold.replace(/na/g, "な"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/a/g, "あ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/be/g, "べ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/de/g, "で"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ge/g, "げ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/he/g, "へ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ke/g, "け"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/me/g, "め"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/pe/g, "ぺ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/re/g, "れ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/se/g, "せ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/te/g, "て"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ze/g, "ぜ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ne/g, "ね");
    hold = hold.replace(/e/g, "え");
    hold = hold.replace(/bi/g, "び"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/gi/g, "ぎ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/hi/g, "ひ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ki/g, "き"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/mi/g, "み"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/pi/g, "ぴ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ri/g, "り"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ji/g, "じ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ni/g, "に"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/i/g, "い");
    hold = hold.replace(/bo/g, "ぼ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/do/g, "ど"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/go/g, "ご"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ho/g, "ほ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ko/g, "こ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/mo/g, "も"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/po/g, "ぽ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ro/g, "ろ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/so/g, "そ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/to/g, "と"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/wo/g, "を"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/yo/g, "よ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/zo/g, "ぞ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/no/g, "の");
    hold = hold.replace(/o/g, "お"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/bu/g, "ぶ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/gu/g, "ぐ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/fu/g, "ふ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ku/g, "く"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/mu/g, "む"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/pu/g, "ぷ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/ru/g, "る"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/su/g, "す"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/yu/g, "ゆ"); 
    hold = hold.replace(/zu/g, "ず");
    hold = hold.replace(/nu/g, "ぬ");
    hold = hold.replace(/u/g, "う");
    hold = hold.replace(/n/g, "ん");
    return hold
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Gist I put together is a Javascript solution (rather than PHP), it only works for Hiragana and Katakana to Romaji, and it doesn't handle all edge-cases, but you might still find it useful as a starting point: https://gist.github.com/Venryx/ecbea1a0c7a8a6cb21d80886488045f1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a morphological analyzer such as https://github.com/siahr/igo-php

You could then grab each word's katakana-only conversion from igo's output:

```php
require_once 'Igo.php';

// '/unidic' is the path to the proprietary dictionary folder *** 
$igo = new Igo("/unidic", "UTF-8");
$parts = $igo->parse($wordString);

function getValueAtIndex($str, $i) {
  $val = explode(',', $str);
  if (isset($val[$i])) {
    return $val[$i];
  }
  return null;
}

$katakanaWords = [];

foreach ($parts as $i => $parts) { 
  $katakanaWords[] = getValueAtIndex($parts->feature, 11);
}

var_dump($katakanaWords);
```

*** You could get a dictionary (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mecab/files/mecab-ipadic/2.7.0-20070801/) to be converted to a format igo could read (such as the /unidic) using igo's own converter (https://osdn.net/projects/igo/downloads/55029/igo-0.4.5.jar/). Using java from the cli, you could run the following:

```bash
java -cp igo-0.4.5.jar net.reduls.igo.bin.BuildDic ipadic mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801 EUC-JP
```

where `mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801` is the folder containing the `*.csv` and `*.def` files. This will output the folder containing the dictionary format igo could read.

The above php code should output the following if the `$wordString` is "走っていた":

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "ハシル" [1]=> string(3) "テ" [2]=> string(6) "イル" [3]=> string(3) "タ" }
```

You could then use the other answers here to convert katakana to romaji.